# Apache Ignite .Net Session Object Serialization

Tags: ignite

I use ignite as session and cache provider. I have a class with IBinarizable interface. ReadBinary and WriteBinary methods only work for cache object serialization. How can i activate these methods for session object serialization ?

```
public class Test : IBinarizable
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }

        public void ReadBinary(IBinaryReader reader)
        {
            A = reader.ReadInt("a");
            B = reader.ReadString("b");
        }

        public void WriteBinary(IBinaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteInt("a", A);
            writer.WriteString("b", B);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do so. Ignite ASP.NET session state provider always uses `BinaryFormatter` to serialize data, and does not support anything else.

The reason is legacy, before 2.0 there were some strict requirements for Binarizable types.